# Join JSON column using an index

Tags: mysql, index, join, json, mysql-8.0

I have two tables:

```
definition (7,000 rows):
+--------------+----------+
| definitionId | nameRef  |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 | [1]      |
|            2 | [1,2]    |
+--------------+----------+


name (millions of rows):
+------------+----------+
| nameId     | name     |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | Maria    |
|          2 | John     |
+------------+----------+
```

`nameRef` is a JSON column, indexed using:

```
CREATE INDEX nameRef ON definition ( ( CAST( nameRef AS UNSIGNED ARRAY ) ) );
```

I'd like to be able to JOIN these tables based on the nameRef, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM definition
JOIN name
ON name.nameId MEMBER OF( definition.nameRef )
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM definition JOIN forename ON name.nameId = JSON_EXTRACT( definition.nameRef, '$[0]' )
```

However both of these are very slow, as they do not use an index.

Is it possible to make this JOIN using an index?

Comment: I tested this but I can't make it use the index either. It will use the index if the query searches for a constant expression, but not if the left argument of MEMBER OF is a column identifier. I wonder if it is simply not implemented. I can't find this restriction in the documentation of the MySQL bug database.

Comment: Regardless, I would not use JSON for this task. Instead, I would create a third table to represent the many-to-many relationship between definitions and names, with one row per pairing of definitionId and nameId. That is the normal way to store many-to-many data.

Comment: Thanks for your help BillKarwin @Ergest Basha.

Comment: *both of these are very slow, as they do not use an index.* You need in `name (nameId)` index primarily... but if the query selects more than 5-7% of rows from `name` then direct tables scanning is more efffective than index usage. If you want you may try to force the indices usage with according index hints.

Comment: Suggestion by @ErgestBasha is only possible with single-dimension JSON objects; not arrays.